# How to determine if something is coplanar within a threshold

Tags: python, math

I have the following (pseudocode):

```
#This is the point I want to check for coplanar 
pointToCheck
#These 3 make the triangle I am using to check pointToCheck against
pointB
pointC
pointD

#Equation 
AB = pointB - pointToCheck
AC = pointC - pointToCheck
AD = pointD - pointToCheck

result = dot(AB, cross(AC, AD))
```

Currenly I know that if result is 0 then they are coplanar but I need a bit more flexibility to say: if result is 0 +- something they are coplanar.

Can some nice person help me out?

Thanks! :)

EDIT:

Maybe I should be asking: Is it possible to do a check to determine the coplanar-ity and receive an angle in return?

For example:
Points A,B,C,D

You are checking Point A against triangle BCD and find that it is not coplanar, but what you get from the formula is an angle that tells you exactly (or nearly) how far off the point is.

Answer (score 0):

In general case you can find equation of the plane and get distance from it.

But you can use good approximation: It seems that you calculate triple product V, and absolute value of |V| corresponds to the volume of tetrahedron ABCD (with some coefficient like 1/6).

So you can divide this volume by area of triangle BCD (magnitude of vector product of BC and CD) and get some approximation of the height (and distance to the plane)

Comment: Can you explain how I should be able to expect the results of this to look in different scenarios?

Comment: You will get distance from BCD plane to A (with some coefficient). Compare it with some tolerance level.